# copy method inside a model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

(Django version 2.+)

I want to implement a **`copy()`** method inside my model `BlogPost` that:

**create a complete copy from this model (object) with these specifications:**

1. Copy the whole post with all its comments
2. Set the date creation to copied date and time
3. Finally return the new blog post (copied) id

My Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from copy import copy, deepcopy


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)


class BlogPost(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     body = models.TextField()
     author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def copy(self):
        pass


class Comment(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

For example, we have:

- One author with the name 'Joe'
- One post with date_created '7 October'
- And 3 comments about this post

After using copy method for this post:

we have one author with 2 posts and 6 comments (each post have 3 separate comments)

Comment: Why does this read like a homework assignment?

Comment: @PeterRowell This is a question in a competition.
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
   def copy(self):
        blog_new = BlogPost()
        blog_new.title=self.title
        blog_new.body = self.body
        blog_new.author = self.author
        blog_new.date_created = self.date_created
        blog_new.save()
        for comment in self.comment_set.all():
            comment.id = None
            comment.blog_post = blog_new
            comment.save()
```

Comment: Tnx for the solution. This method working properly but isn't complete.
please consider with the explanation in the question that I wrote.